# Can access joomla via ip but not through domain (Warning: require_once error)

Tags: php, joomla

All of a sudden one of my [client's sites stopped working](http://www.logosist.com/)

Error:

> Warning: require_once(/home/logosist/public_html/includes/defines.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/logosist/public_html/index.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/logosist/public_html/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/logosist/public_html/index.php on line 18

From the error I can see that the directory path is wrong:

Should be

`/home/public_html/logosist/includes/defines.php`

and not

`/home/logosist/public_html/includes/defines.php`

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Open your `index.php`, look at line 18, work backwards from there.

Comment: `define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
 include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
 define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
 require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';`

Comment: This is not an issue with the *index.php* file. **DO NOT** change it! Check with your hosting to see if they have changed any server settings. If you're Joomla site was working before and all of a sudden has gone wrong, then this is not your fault but a server related issue. Also make sure you never move or edit any core Joomla files

Comment: Are you sure the path is wrong? The errors claim that `/home/logosist/public_html/` is the path of your `index.php`, why would your `includes/defines.php` file be elsewhere? To get the obvious out of the way, does a `defines.php` file exist under that path? @Lodder I didn't tell him to change the file, I told him to look there so he can learn to troubleshoot. Server related issues are the last thing on my troubleshooting steps.. there's too many other variables not accounted for here.

Comment: @sjagr - I know you didn't tell him to do this. I was making sure he didn't make any changes to it. A lot of people start changing core Joomla files and then wonder why their site doesn't work ;)

Comment: /Includes/ is still under Joomla. The path to Joomla installation changed!

Comment: logosist is the name of the Joomla folder, and should be public_html/logosist and not logosist/public_html

Comment: But is `define.php` under `/includes/`??? Your `index.php` is reporting the correct path my friend... you're just jumping to the wrong conclusion @Lodder Or delete core files ;)

Comment: Yes. define.php is under /includes/ and this started to happen all of a sudden

Comment: @PeterPupovac You need to give your hosting company a ring.

Answer (score 0):

Check you directories and files access permissions. I don't think that it is path problem. I've had the same and setting correct permissions solved it.